# event schedule error mark near END on mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

as you can see on pictures above, i try to create delete event for rows old than 7 days,  on mysql but the problem when i check the event it's have error mark near `END` but yeah if just press go it's going without error or any debug but iam not sure if the code will be executed automaticaly by mysql, so what's wrong with this code? ty for advance

Comment: Can you check `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler'` if its `ON`?

Comment: ialready check it using SHOW PROCESSLIST; it's ON

Comment: and using this SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler' is on too.

Comment: What ide is that?